# MSMQ ,reading multiple Queue messages from a single windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I need some design suggestions if any one could suggest one that would be great.

I implemented a WCF service that reads messages from a queue(MSMQ) on windows server and processes it further.Now I need to read the messages from another queue and process them seperately.I am confused to go with a new service or update the existing service which would do the both readings from different queues parallel.

I am thinking interms of performance which would be the best option to go ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just have a separate thread for each consumer. Below is the pseudo code. The only things you need to make sure is to signal stop to threads when service is being shut down.

```
new Thread(WorkerA) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
new Thread(WorkerB) { IsBackground = true }.Start();

void WorkerA() {
   while (true) { /* process queue a */ }
}

void WorkerB() {
   while (true) { /* process queue b */ }
}
```

Performance should be equivalent when talking about 1 service vs 2 services because it will still be a thread being scheduled by the operating system. As for stability, you could be a little more resilient when splitting the services, but that still shouldn't be too much of an issue, I would expect that the single service approach should be stable enough within each thread.

In the end I would just go for the simplest approach.